# aptana report python type error

Tags: python, aptana, pydev

I use Aptana to write Python code. Aptana often report error due to the fact that there is no type information bound to names in python.

Let's say:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = None

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def someMethod(self):
        pass

#in the main function 

a = A()
a.m = B()
a.m.someMethod() #Aptana will report a error here since it does not know a.m has such method.
```

similar cases exist. It is not a big problem to ignore them but is there an elegant way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might [pyDev Content Assistants](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_assistants.html) help?